# JSON from datatables in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Try to make JSON from datatable using JsonConvert.SerializeObject like this

```
Dim str As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
```

It is working fine but the required JSON has child node as well whereas datatable has no option to make child node

```
{
    "InvNo": "1",
    "DateTime": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "Name": "Customer Name",
    "PhoneNumber": "0000-0000000",
    "BillAmount": "0.0",
    "Quantity": "0.0",
    "Value": 0.0,
    "Discount": 0.0,
    "Type": 1,
    "Items": [
        {
            "I_Code": "IT_1011",
            "I_Name": "Test Item",
            "I_Quantity": 1.0,
            "I_TaxRate": 0.0,
            "I_Sale": 0.0,
            "I_T_Amount": 0.0,
            "I_Discount": 0.0
        },
        {
            "I_Code": "IT_1012",
            "I_Name": "Test Item",
            "I_Quantity": 1.0,
            "I_TaxRate": 0.0,
            "I_Sale": 0.0,
            "I_T_Amount": 0.0,
            "I_Discount": 0.0
        }
    ]
}
```

could not find any solution to add child node in json using datatable or should i have to use some other way?

Comment: Have you considered using regular classes instead of trying to shoehorn this into a DataTable?

Comment: As data is already stored in datatable so making json from datatable wuold be easy, i thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DataTable is set up like this:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("InvNo", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("DateTime", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("BillAmount", GetType(Decimal))
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Decimal))
dt.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Decimal))
dt.Columns.Add("Discount", GetType(Decimal))
dt.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Items", GetType(DataTable))

Dim inner as New DataTable()
inner.Columns.Add("I_Code", GetType(String))
inner.Columns.Add("I_Name", GetType(String))
inner.Columns.Add("I_Quantity", GetType(Decimal))
inner.Columns.Add("I_TaxRate", GetType(Decimal))
inner.Columns.Add("I_Sale", GetType(Decimal))
inner.Columns.Add("I_T_Amount", GetType(Decimal))
inner.Columns.Add("I_Discount", GetType(Decimal))

inner.Rows.Add("IT_1011", "Test Item", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
inner.Rows.Add("IT_1012", "Test Item", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

dt.Rows.Add("1", "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "Customer Name", "0000-0000000", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1, inner)
```

You can get the JSON you want like this:

```
Dim json = JToken.FromObject(dt).First.ToString()
```

Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XRmJMZ